# ubuntu: including boost to eclipse CDT when installed from Aptitude

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, include, eclipse-cdt

I am new to both C++ and eclipse and I am trying to use smart pointers.

I installed boost using aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

then in my eclipse project I added "boost" to

```
/ properties / c/c++build / settings / cross G++ linker / Libraries /
```

now in my C++ I try to include smart pointers:

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.h>
```

but I am told : unresolved inclusion: boost/smart_ptr.h

I am really not sure why. From my (limited) understanding, I should not need to look for the path to to the libboost and to the include path of the compiler. I based this on the fact that I included other libraries installed by aptitude and I could include them in my code directly.

Sounds like a basic question, but all the threads I could find were either about windows, or about boost being downloaded and manually compiled (in which case I understand the path has to be given to the compiler).

Anything I am missing ?

Thx a lot

Comment: You usually don't have to do anything. But the header is probably boost/shared_ptr.hpp.

Comment: @juanchopanza Indeed ! Thanks a lot ... not sure if I should feel stupid or not. The examples I saw online were importing .h. In general, how to get to know that ?

Comment: Boost uses .hpp, and you can see that from the code examples on their website.

Comment: ok, my conclusion is : trust the examples of the official website, not the example of some random dude online --; do feel kinda stupid at the end. anyway, thx for the help